# While Loop in Azure SQL

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop, declare

In the Azure Stream Analytics Query I want to write a `WHILE` loop using `DECLARE/SET` for counting.

```
DECLARE @x int
SET @x = 0
WHILE @x < 90
BEGIN
SET @x = @x + 1

*My code with '@x' as a counter*

END
```

The error message claims:

> DECLARE @x int is an unsupported statement.

Is there something basic that I overlooked?

If I comment out the `DECLARE` command, ASA SQL doesn't like the `SET` command.

If I leave out the `WHILE` loop and replace `@x` with a number in my code, everything works fine.

Comment: merge the declare and set into one line maybe?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-loops  and you might be missing ;

Comment: Unfortunately, merging and adding the semicolon didn't help. The example you give also gives the syntax error when run, telling me there is a mistake at the WHILE loop.

Comment: out of curiosity, try changing @x = @x +1 to @x += 1.  probably won't do anything, but worth trying

Comment: Thanks Marshall. Unfortunately doesn't help, tried a lot of these little things. Always the same error.

Comment: maybe the capitalization matters?  INT instead of int?

Comment: tried int and INT, also bigint and BIGINT. Strange thing is, whatever I write first in my code gets the error message. Even "USE" commands. Makes it super hard to find the mistake.

Comment: you said you replaced all the @x values with a number.  Have you tried slowly adding them back to see where the real error is?  e.g. add the declare statement back first, then the set, then the while loop, etc?

Comment: I tried this. Even the DECLARE alone, with whatever formulation, results in the same error. :'(